# Custom order in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

We are querying database to retrieve data in following fashion

select a,b,...f from table1 where id in (6,33,1,78,2)

The result I got from query is in following order 1,2,6,33,78.

I want the result in same order (6,33,1,78,2). Is there any way to retrieve the data in same order.

**EDIT**
**I am using SQL 2008**

Comment: What DB engine are yuo using?

Comment: Removed the (irrelevant) C# tag. @Ram: I suppose you don't want solution in C# for this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

add this order by clause

```
order by case 
         when id = 6 then 1 
         when id = 33 then 2  
         when id = 1 then 3  
         when id = 78 then 4  
         when id = 2 then 5  
      end
```

If using MySQL you can do this

```
ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(id, '6,33,1,78,2')
```

Answer (score 3):

Using a [Table Value Constructor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd776382%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

```
SELECT a, b, ... f 
FROM 
        table1 
    JOIN
        ( VALUES 
            (1,  6), 
            (2, 33), 
            (3,  1), 
            (4, 78), 
            (5,  2) 
        ) AS ordering (position, id)
      ON  ordering.id = table1.id
ORDER BY position
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the background, but usually I achieve this custom order in an additional orderIndex column. This way I can manually manage the order when inserting to the table and add this column to the ORDER BY clause of the default queries

Comment: Note: this can be indexed so the performance won't be a problem like in case in a hard-to-manage CASE-ing solution.

Answer (score 2):

If you use SQL Server you could use `charindex`.

```
select A, B
from Table1
where ID in (6,33,1,78,2)
order by charindex(','+cast(ID as varchar(10))+',', ',6,33,1,78,2,')
```

Answer (score 1):

ugly solution:

```
select a,b,...f from table1 where id in 6
UNION
select a,b,...f from table1 where id in 33
and so on..
```

"better" solution:
add another column on your query and do case 6 then 0, case 33 then 1 and so on

```
select a,b,...f , case id when 6 then 0 when 33 then 1 <and so on> end
from table1 where ...
```

and then  order by this new column